# Casting from object to ArrayList in Java Servlets sessions

Tags: java, session, servlets, casting, arraylist

i am facing a persistent problem in  casting , i tried too much but i can't solve.
i want to store an ArrayList in java servlet session

```
//create ArrayList<User> and store in session
ArrayList<User> listOfUsers=new ArrayList<User>();
session.setAttribute("listOfUsers",listOfUsers);
```

But when i come to cast the ArrayList object to retrieve from the session i get the following warning:
 "Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to ArrayList"

```
//casting with Warning
ArrayList <User> users=(ArrayList<User>)session.getAttribute("listOfUsers");
```

And that causes null values when i run the website and trying to execute the following

```
String username=users.get(i).uname;
out.print("User:"+username);
```

How Can I Solve this casting to be correct ? 
thanks in advance for any help

Comment: The warning has not anything to do with the Null values. As another note: program to interfaces than implementations. List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>(); and List<User> users=(List<User>)session.getAttribute("listOfUsers");

Comment: so why aren't the array objects values displayed?. i get null exceptions

Comment: its something else in the code that creates your problem

Answer (score 0):

If null values are being printed, then casting isn't the issue. If the list was null, you'd get a `NullPointerException` when you call `user.get(index)`. Has `User.uname` been set? Did you populate the list? If you try to access `uname` on a null object you'll get an exception too.

Comment: i created object regUser with all parameters set then added like this    ArrayList<User> temp=new ArrayList<User>();
    temp.add(regUser);
    session.setAttribute("listOfUsers",temp);